# Setting up setOnMarkerClickListener() without losing .setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Simple and quickly question I can't find the answer:

I am using google maps with cluster Manager. To configure it, I use this :

```
private void setUpClusterMap() {
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, map);
    mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyItemRenderer());
    mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new GridBasedAlgorithm<MyItem>());
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
}
```

the problem is that, now I want to add a custom setOnMarkerClickListener(), how can I do it without losing setOnClusterClickListener or setOnClusterItemClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering):

> If you want to add specific functionality in response to a marker
>   click event, set the map's OnMarkerClickListener() to the
>   ClusterManager, since ClusterManager implements the listener.